# Web scraping with python how to get to the text

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get the text from a website but can't find a way do to it. How do I need to write it?

```
link="https://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-5553905,00.html"
response = requests.get(link)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
info = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'text14'})
name = info.text.strip()
print(name)
```

This is how it looks:
[image]

i'm getting none everytime

Comment: Your screenshot shows the DOM while beautifulsoup operates on the source. They can differ.

Comment: Did you try this `response = requests.get(link).text`?

Comment: @Amir it's giving the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
link="https://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-5553905,00.html" 
response = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser') 
info = soup.findAll('script',attrs={'type':"application/ld+json"})[0].text.strip()
jsonDict = json.loads(info)
print(jsonDict['articleBody'])
```

The page seems to store all the article data in json in the `<script>` tag so try this code.

Comment: what about in this case: https://www.ynetnews.com/articles/0,7340,L-5554655,00.html ? any idea how to get the text? it's not working well in my way and not in yours as well

Answer (score 1):

The solution is :

```
info = soup.find('meta', attrs={'property':'og:description'})
```

It gave me the text i needed